# curl to RESTapi specifying queryParam, pathParam and formData

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, curl

I'm writing a RestController which contains an API which is supposed to take as input a QueryParam, a PathParam and a FormData. I'll show you the code:

```
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden/Request Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 412, message = "Client Error"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request accepted") })
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "POST", value = "Some description", tags = {
        "some tag" }, notes = "some note")
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = { "/foo/bar/{id}" }, produces = {
        "application/json" }, consumes = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity moveDPO(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
        @RequestParam(value = "endpoint") @ApiParam(required = true, allowEmptyValue = false, example = "https://endpoint.com") String endpoint,
        @RequestPart(value = "json") String json)
```

As you can see, here I have three parameters:

- id -> the path param
- endpoint -> the query param
- json -> the formData (it is a json)

I'm trying to call this RESTapi with curl in this way

```
curl -d 'json={"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", ...}' https://mydomain/foo/bar/3541832?endpoint=https://someendpoint.com -H "Authorization: basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" -H "content-type: application/json"
```

However, when I try, what I get is the following error:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-08-20T14:45:36.940+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/json","path":"/foo/bar/3541832"}
```

I cannot figure out how to make it work. Why the RESTapi is expecting a multipart/form-data? It is because of the @RequestPart annotation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Basically, there were three errors:

- First one, the `-d` option refers to the body. In my case, I wanted to send data as formData, so `-F` (or `--form`) is the correct option
- Second, the queryParam was not url-encoded
- Third, the content-type must be `"content-type: multipart/form-data"`

The final correct curl is the following:

`curl -F 'json={"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", ...}' https://mydomain/foo/bar/3541832?endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsomeendpoint.com -H "Authorization: basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" -H "content-type: multipart/form-data"`